# 'type' does not contain a definition for 'member' and no extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm pretty new to using anything related to graphics in my programs and I'm stumped because it's giving me the error `'type' does not contain a definition for 'member' and no extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found`. I've instantiated the object and it's still giving me issues and I'm just trying to call the auto generated code that visual studio made for a windows panel.

Here is the code for the main:

```
namespace TesterProject 
{
  public class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       logInOut person = new logInOut(); 
       Display visualizer = new Display();

       visualizer.Display();

       person.login();

    }    
  }    
}
```

And here is the class I'm trying to call (Display):

```
namespace TesterProject
{
  public partial class Display : Form
  {
    public Display()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Any help you guys can provide would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Removing the C++ tag, since this doesn't seem to be C++.

Comment: `Display` is not a method. It is the constructor of the type named `Display`.

Comment: The form `Display` doesn't contain a method `Display`, you need to call `Show()`.

Comment: Thank you so much Ron Beyer! I feel like dummy but that was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a constructor:

```
public Display()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

So when you call this:

```
Display visualizer = new Display();
```

It is actually the constructor that is called, so you don't need to try and call it again.

Seems like it should just be:

```
namespace TesterProject 
{

public class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       logInOut person = new logInOut(); 
       Display visualizer = new Display();

       person.login();
   }    
 }    
}
```